# Database using Sqlite in C# windows phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have doubt regarding windows phone 8 application development. The database using sqlite for windows phone 8 is pre-loaded into the application or it should be created dynamically at the time of installation in windows phone..? and if it is pre-loaded then how to create the database.db file..?? and also if it is dynamically created, what is the procedure to create dynamically...??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who are not able to work with sqlite I would like to suggest them to follow this link : http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx and when you are dumping the data into the project .. you just need to change the properties of the "database1.sqlite" i.e. Build Action = resource . Thats all you need to do ..

Answer (score 1):

I would say, pre-loaded into the application is the very common way.

Take a look at this article, I think the steps to accomplish your task are quite the same: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/import-an-already-existing-sqlite-database-in-a-windows-8-application/

The first step is to copy your database in to the Visual Studio project and, from the Properties window, set the Build action to Content.

Once you’ve done this operation, you’ll be able to access to the files embedded in your project thanks to the Package.Current.InstalledLocation object that is available in the Windows.ApplicationModel namespace.

The InstalledLocation’s type is StorageFolder, which is the base class of all the folders mapping in WinRT: for this reason, it exposes all the standard methods to interact with the storage, like getting a file or a folder. This way we can use the GetFileAsync method to get a reference to the database embedded into the project and, after that, using the CopyAsync method we can copy it into the local storage of the application. We can copy it in the root of the local storage (like in the following example) or in a specific folder, by getting a reference to it first using the GetFolderAsync method.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to create database dynamically .. if it is possible ..

Comment: Sanghati, it is definitely possible but I personally have not done this yet. Maybe this thread can help you, please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647868/how-can-i-create-a-new-sqlite-database-with-all-tables-on-the-fly

Comment: finally it worked .. For those who are not able to work with sqlite I would like to suggest them to follow this link :

**[link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)** 

and when you are dumping the data into the project .. you just need to change the properties of the "database1.sqlite" i.e. Build Action = resource . Thats all you need to do ..